# redirect to same site, but different link (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I want that people in "example.com/index.htm" get redirected to "example.com".
 but the code is being tricky. It always takes me to a loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
 if (window.top!="example.com") 
 {
  window.location="http://example.com";
 }else {} 
}</script>
```

Comment: sure it will as `index.htm` is your default page and when you access `mysite.com` browser actually get `mysite.com/index.htm` so there sure is a infinite re-direct loop.

Comment: You should really be doing this at the web server level using rewrite conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
if (window.top.location.href!="http://mysite.com") 
 {
window.top.location.href="http://mysite.com";
}else {} 
}</script>
```

You need to use the location object and it needs to actually match.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go (untested):

```
$(function() {

    var reg = /index.htm/g,
        top = window.location.href,
        loc = '';

    if(reg.test(top)) {

        top = top.replace('http://','');
        top = top.split('/');

        for(i=0;i<top.length-1;i++) {
            loc = loc + top[i];
        }

        window.location.href = 'http://' + loc;
    }

});
```